# How do I disable inserting a new empty line when I press Enter when the cursor is in brackets?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Steps to reproduce:

- simple code:
  `if () {}`
- cursor is between `{}`
- i press Enter
- result:

```js
if () {
  
}
```

- expected result:

```js
if () {
}
```

I want a empty line not to be inserted.

It may be that it works by default(adds a empty line), and when `Alt+Enter` it doesn't add a empty line.

I did not find settings in vscode. I didn't find anything on google.

---

I tried this:

```json
{
  "key": "alt+enter",
  "command": "type",
  "args": { 
    "text": "\n" 
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

Because `Alt+Enter` does nothing by default.
However, the `onEnterRules` function used with the `editor.autoIndent` option detects the addition of the `\n` character and adds an extra empty line anyway. :(

I want to use `editor.autoIndent`. But I want to turn off (do not turn on) using the shortcut `Alt+Enter`.

---

Worst option: look for an extension that does exactly the same as `editor.autoIndent`, but has the ability to create a shortcut `Alt+Enter` to work the way I want.

Comment: Every time I do a find on google I find a lot. There database is HUGE.

Comment: Very unlikely that if you want to split `{}` you don't want to insert some text, and typing that text on the same line as the `}` is bad practice and will lead to problems later

Comment: @rioV8 It's about when I have some code and then want to insert it into a conditional statement. I then move the line with the code (using the Alt + UpArrow shortcut), and there is an empty line that I have to delete anyway. When I do it one more time, it is annoying. Snippet with TM_SELECTED_TEXT or CLIPBOARD is even more steps to do, so that's out of the question. Just not adding a empty line solves my problem.

Comment: @rioV8 The trick is that you have to use the right keywords to find something specific. I'm looking for "vscode enter insert new empty line" shows up a lot, but nothing I would need. : /

Comment: @rioV8 I found that the `editor.autoIndent` option adds a empty line. But in general I want to use indent, just DO NOT ADD a empty line I want to have under a separate keyboard shortcut.  There it is called `onEnterRules`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extension [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) and construct a command that does what you want.

Add this to your `settings.json` (global or workspace)

```json
  "multiCommand.commands": {
    "multiCommand.lineBreakNoEmptyline": {
      "sequence": [
        "lineBreakInsert",
        "deleteWordRight",
        "cursorRight",
        "cursorHome"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Add this to your `keybindings.json`:

```json
  {
    "key": "alt+enter",
    "command": "multiCommand.lineBreakNoEmptyline",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  }
```

Or using the keybinding only method

```json
  {
    "key": "alt+enter",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": { 
      "sequence": [
        "lineBreakInsert",
        "deleteWordRight",
        "cursorRight",
        "cursorHome"
      ]
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  }
```

Comment: There is a clear jump when using `multi-command` - add and then delete the line.
But it is still a very good solution to my problem.

Comment: Using these commands is a little cleaner: `  {"command": "type", "args": {"text": "\n"}}, "editor.action.clipboardCutAction"`.

Comment: @lukaszpolowczyk you can try Mark's suggestion with clipboardCutAction

Comment: @Mark @rioV8 It doesn't work at all. I don't know what the issue is: 
`  {
    "key": "alt+enter",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": { 
      "sequence": [
        {"command": "type", "args": {"text": "\n"}},
        "editor.action.clipboardCutAction"
      ]
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },`

Answer (score 0):

I'll show the info from my comment here so that it is clearer.  This keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+enter",                // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
    "sequence": [
      // "lineBreakInsert",
      {
        "command": "type", 
        "args": {
          "text": "\n"
        }
      },
      "editor.action.clipboardCutAction"
    ]
  },
}
```

The `type` command acts differently than a `lineBreakInsert` command so it is a little easier to then delete that extra line as the cursor is already there.  It is just a small improvement, 2 less commands.

Demo:

[image: delete inserted lineBreak macro example]

Comment: It's still not working for me.
I don't know how you do it.
Version: 1.68.0
Commit: 4af164ea3a06f701fe3e89a2bcbb421d2026b68f
Date: 2022-06-08T11:49:57.055Z
Electron: 17.4.7
Chromium: 98.0.4758.141
Node.js: 16.13.0
V8: 9.8.177.13-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.10.7-arch1-1

Comment: You are putting that into your `keybindings.json`?  And when it isn't working - does nothing happen when you trigger the keybinding?

Comment: And you are using whatever keybinding you assigned to this shortcut?

Comment: This is what it looks like: https://i.ibb.co/JcZ3jTG/ctrl-k.gif
It adds a new line (as it normally does), but does not delete itself.
And the combination from rioV8 works as I wanted.

Comment: @rioV8 Does my version above work for you?